# Timestamp 'xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xx+xxxx' is not recognized

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm doing a copy into a table but I'm seeing this error, I don't understand because it looks like a timestamp datatype? is it the 'T' that is effecting this?

The data is cleaned using a pandas df, sent to a csv file that I'm trying to ingest to Snowflake.

I'm wondering if I should change the END_TIME row formatting in pandas like `(df['end_time']=pd.to_datetime(dfend_time'])`_ or is there another way to ingest to snowflake as is?

> Timestamp '2021-09-17T07:00:00+0000' is not recognized
> Row 1, column "FACEBOOK_INSIGHTS"["END_TIME":8]

```
COPY INTO fbk.fbk_insights
FROM (
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP::TIMESTAMP_LTZ, METADATA$FILENAME, METADATA$FILE_ROW_NUMBER, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7
    FROM @luigi.etc/FBK/insights/2021-09-19/
)
file_format = (format_name = 'fbk.fbk_insights')


TRUNCATECOLUMNS = FALSE
FORCE = FALSE
```

Comment: Try converting the timestamp to character using strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'). This solved a similar error when writing a data frame to Snowflake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake supports a variety of input formats, take a look at these to see if it suites.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#time-formats

If you are not able to find the transformation / format that suites then I'd do as Maja suggests, import and then convert